# Load Local Geojson Data with Leaflet and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I am displaying in my Vue.js a leaflet Map with Geojson Data.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([13.82, 106.62], 5);

  // load a tile layer
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 6
    }).addTo(map);


  // The rodents json data need to be replace by a proper HTTPS not local Server   
  map.setZoom(4);
  $.getJSON("C:\Users\simon\Desktop\FE\data\heat.geojson",function(data){
    var locations = data.features.map(function(gps) {
      // the heatmap plugin wants an array of each location
      var location = gps.geometry.coordinates.reverse();
      location.push(1.0);
      return location; // e.g. [50.5, 30.5, 0.2], // lat, lng, intensity
    });

    var heat = L.heatLayer(locations, { radius: 25, maxOpacity: .8, scaleRadius: false, valueField: 'total',

    // gradient: {
    //         0.0: 'green',
    //         0.5: 'yellow',
    //         1.0: 'red'
    //     } 


    });

    map.addLayer(heat);
  });
```

On a local browser, I will simply load the data from the file location and it will work. How can I load the data in my local vue.js application?\

```
If i Change path to : HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:8082/pages/..FE/data/sales_vietnam_heat.geojson
```